# How to root login to remote machine in using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, expect

I want to root login of a remote machine using shell script.
I tried with below shell command , I am able to login to remote machine , but I am unable to root login of remote machine.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20   
set ip [lindex $argv 0]    
set user [lindex $argv 1]    
set password [lindex $argv 2]    
spawn ssh "$user\@$ip"    
expect "Password:"

send "$password\r";    
expect "/u/ainet->"
spawn "su -"
expect "Password:"
send "mypasswd\r";

interact
```

The above shell only prompt me to `/u/ainet->`, but I not able to execute the below command:

```
spawn "su -"
expect "Password:"
send "mypasswd\r";
```

Comment: Can you do it manually?

Comment: Once you get this working, you'll have this shell script file sitting on your computer with the other computer's root password in it. That's not very secure. You should set up an ssh key which permits you to connect to the other system as root and run whatever command you're trying to automate. There are ways to make that secure, and it'd be much less of a headache than this expect script.

Answer (score 0):

on remote machine, edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
PermitRootLogin = yes
```

then save & exit, restart sshd service

Comment: You didn't answer the question. The OP doesn't want to ssh as `root` user, he tries to execute `su -` on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer your question directly, as in: I don't know how to handle the password prompt properly.
My advice is to avoid prompts though. You can do this by allowing passwordless sudo commands. 
[explained here](https://serverfault.com/q/160581)